# Converting limits of a triple integral from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration

$\iiint_{B}z\cdot\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}dxdydz$ when B represents the the bounded area between $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and $z=1$

When I draw it it looks like a Paraboloid but I still don't figure out what are the limits when I convert it to cylindrical coordinates.

Can you explain me what the limits are and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The region is actually cone-shaped (a paraboloid would be $z = x^2 + y^2$). As for your actual question: $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ amounts to $z^2 = r^2$, or $z = r$ for $z > 0$, so you can integrate from $z = r$ to $z = 1$. $r$ will obviously go from $0$ to $1$, and $\theta$ will run from $0$ to $2\pi$. So, your limits will look like $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{r}^{1} dz dr d\theta$.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry it's supposed to be z without the square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, advice:  You can't survive triple integrals if you aren't familiar with quadric surfaces.  There are only 6 and you should be able to recognize them on sight.  $z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a cone.  The vertex is at the origin.  It's cut at $z=1$, so it's a pretty plain looking cone.  It's equation in cylindrical is $z^2=r^2$, but we can take it as $z=r.$

Now, for the limits.  Normally, one looks for a top surface and a bottom surface, and here was have $z=1$ and the cone, respectively.  If you project the cone onto
the $xy$-plane, it's a circle of radius $1$, which is easy to set up in polar.  So the integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r \int_r^1 \mbox{crud}\; r \; dz\; dr\; d\theta.$$

Edit:  After your edit, the equation of the paraboloid is $z=r^2$, so the last bottom limit is $r^2.$

Comment: One of us has made a minor error somewhere. I see you have $dr d\theta$, but where is $dz$? And since $r^2 = z^2$ should correspond to $r = z$, why do you have the integrand for $z$ (presumably) run from $r$ to $2$, rather than $r$ to $1$?

Comment: @Chris  Thanks.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @Typhon  "Crud" was a G-C Rota-ism.  It's a highly technical term meaning "stuff that only distracts from the current thought."